# Move div on click of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This seems to be something that should be simple, but I can not figure it out. I have 2 divs and one is hidden behind the other. When you click the top div the bottom div slides out. I have the css but I need it to stay out not just when it is hovered. So I tried using onclick event to change the css name but it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

**The HTML**

```
<div onclick="searchShow();" class="header-cart-search-button"> </div>
<div class="header-cart-search-wrapper">
        [search form goes here]
</div>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript**

```
<script>
    function scriptShow() {
        $('.header-cart-search-wrapper').addClass( "header-cart-search-wrapper-clicked" ); 
    }
</script>
```

And then while I am here, how would I hide it again on another click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other poster as already pointed out, you have a typo in your code, and referring to the wrong function (`searchShow` vs `scriptShow`?)

You will want to use jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method to alternate between shown and hidden states (I assume you set CSS transitions for it to have the sliding behaviour you mentioned):

`$('.header-cart-search-wrapper').toggleClass('header-cart-search-wrapper-clicked');`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a typo. In your HTML, you've called `searchShow()`, but in your JavaScript, you've defined a function called `scriptShow()`.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to inner div

```
<div class="header-cart-search-wrapper" id="wrapper">

if($('#wrapper').hasClass('header-cart-search-wrapper-clicked')) {
  $(#wrapper).removeClass('header-cart-search-wrapper-clicked');
}
else {
  $(#wrapper).addClass('header-cart-search-wrapper-clicked');
}
```

Instead you can use toogleClass()